# How to pass all pages of pdf to create a word cloud?

Tags: python, numpy, word-cloud, pypdf

I am currently new to this concept of word clouds and found a simple way of passing text to word cloud. But I want to pass on the pdf's to the wordcloud.generate() function in python. I am using the code below and able to create a cloud for particular page the line pdfReader.numPages gives me the page count but I am not able to figure out how to loop it.

**Sample Code**

```
from wordcloud import WordCloud
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import PyPDF4

pdfFileObj = open('ReadyPlayerOne.pdf', 'rb')
pdfReader = PyPDF4.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)
print(pdfReader.numPages)
pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(0)
print(pageObj.extractText())
pdfFileObj.close()

ourMask = np.array(Image.open('twitter_mask.png'))

cloud = WordCloud(background_color='white', mask=ourMask ).generate(pageObj.extractText())

plt.imshow(cloud)
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay so I figured it out but by the other way posting the answer just for the reference but other optimal solutions are most welcome.

**Code for the loop**

```
pdfReader = PyPDF4.PdfFileReader(open('ReadyPlayerOne.pdf', 'rb'))
pageData = ''
for page in pdfReader.pages:
    pageData += page.extractText()
    print(pageData)
```

Comment: Great help with your code for the loop, thanks!